# Use js file with angular (d.ts file)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, .d.ts

I try since yesterday to write a correct d.ts file in order to use my personal js file into angular.io

This is a piece of my js file :

```
let usersSpeak = {};
let remoteStreams = [];
let idSpeaker;
function updateUser(id, value) {
   //do something
}

function stop(type, id) {
    //do something
}
```

For the moment my d.ts file looks like this :

```
declare namespace MyNamespace {
   let usersSpeak: any;
   let idSpeaker: number;
   let remoteStreams: any;
   function updateUser(id: number, value: string);
   function stop(type: string, id: number);
}
```

I know this can't work because i create a namespace MyNamespace which doesn't exist on my js.file but i tried a lot of things and nothing work...
I succeed with this on my ts file directly :

```
declare let usersSpeak: any;
declare let idSpeaker: any;
declare let remoteStreams: any;
declare let updateUser: any;
declare let stop: any;
```

But that's not what i want, i really want a d.ts file

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: You understand that TypeScript transpiles to JavaScript, correct? Your d.ts is still going to be converted to d.js.

Comment: Yeah but i need to have this d.ts and my problem is i don't find the correct syntax

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
export namespace MyNameSpace {
   let usersSpeak: any;
   let idSpeaker: number;
   let remoteStreams: any;
   function updateUser(id: number, value: string);
   function stop(type: string, id: number);
}
```

Comment: I import my d.ts file like this : /// <reference path="../mynamespace.d.ts"/>  and import {Omswebrtc} from '../mynamespace'; unfornatally i have this error : mynamespace.d.ts' is not a module.